# Flash Paint Api

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create an flash paint application along with the layers where each and every component will be associated with the layers along with the property panel which will display all the properties of the components e.g. rectangle with fill and stroke, line with stroke propertty.

So, that user can manipulate the components as per his requirement. Can anyone tell me about such library which provide such type of features.

Comment: I don't think you can just put some parts together... You'll have put work into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any library that provides all that functionality. However, you can start with a library like http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/ and then build up your app specific needs from there (such as adding your own property panels).